# Why Wordpress post_name is returning multiple values?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the current page slug by using `get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() )`, however, this is returning multiple values.

My code looks like this (I'm writing this in a custom plugin):

```php
function prefix_filter_query( $query_string, $grid_id, $action ) {

    // If the content is not filtered on first render.
    if ( 'render' === $action && empty( $query_string ) ) {
        $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );
        
        $query_string = [
            'categories' => [ $slug ]
        ];
    
        _error_log($slug);
    }
    
    return $query_string;
    
}

function _error_log ($value) {
    error_log(print_r($value, true), 3, __DIR__ . '/log.txt');
    error_log("\r\n\r\n", 3, __DIR__ . '/log.txt');
}

add_filter( 'wp_grid_builder/facet/query_string', 'prefix_filter_query', 10, 3 );
```

The log is showing first the current page (here a category, like 'hoodies'), and then the homepage slug of my website, like this :

```
hoodies

home
```

I understood that home was showed because I set the home page of my website to be the static default homepage. I tried to disable it and see if it solved my issue but then the second value returned by the log was just an empty space:

```
hoodies
```

I want to get only `hoodies` and I don't understand why there's a second value, whether it is home or an empty value.

To give a bit of context, I'm using a filter plugin for products in an e-commerce website and the plugin is giving a built-in function to filter the content before it is rendered. https://docs.wpgridbuilder.com/resources/filter-facet-query-string/
Another interesting fact, in our example, `hoodies` will successfully filter the grid of items to show only hoodies but the query in the URL will be `?_categories=home`.

**Solution found 28/12/2021**

I got an answer from the plugin support (WP Grid Builder) and the issue was that my code was incompatible with the Ajax requests made by WP Grid Builder. Here's the solution I was provided:

```php
add_filter(
    'wp_grid_builder/facet/query_string',
    function( $query_string, $grid_id, $action ) {

        global $post;


        if ( 'render' === $action && empty( $query_string ) ) {

            $referer   = wp_get_referer();
            $post_id   = wp_doing_ajax() ? url_to_postid( $referer ) : $post->ID;
            $post_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $post_id );

            $query_string = [
                'categories' => [ $post_slug ],
            ];

        }

        return $query_string;

    },
    10,
    3
);
```

Comment: move the function out of the function

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I edited the original post and moved `_error_log` out of the function. It is still logging `hoodies` and `home` though, did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to get the current page slug ? You could go through the server request uri `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

### `PHP >= 8.0.0`

```
<?php

/**
 * Retrieve the current page slug.
 * 
 * @return String The current page slug.
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_the_current_slug' ) ) {

    function get_the_current_slug() {

        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if ( str_contains( $url, '?' ) ) {
        
            $url = substr( $url, 0, strpos( $url, '?' ) );
        
        };
        
        $slugs = ( str_ends_with( $url, '/' ) ? explode( '/', substr( $url, 1, -1 ) ) : explode( '/', substr( $url, 1 ) ) );
        
        return end( $slugs );

    };

};
```

### `PHP < 8.0.0` (eg: `7.x.x`)

```
<?php

/**
 * Checks if a string ends with a given substring.
 * 
 * @param String $haystack The string to search in.
 * @param String $needle The substring to search for in the haystack.
 * 
 * @return Integer < 0 if haystack from position offset is less than needle, > 0 if it is greater than needle, and 0 if they are equal. If offset is equal to (prior to PHP 7.2.18, 7.3.5) or greater than the length of haystack, or the length is set and is less than 0, substr_compare() prints a warning and returns false.
 * 
 * @see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'startsWith' ) ) {

    function startsWith( $haystack, $needle ) {

        return substr_compare( $haystack, $needle, 0, strlen( $needle ) ) === 0;

    };

};

/**
 * Retrieve the current page slug.
 * 
 * @return String The current page slug.
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_the_current_slug' ) ) {

    function get_the_current_slug() {

        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if ( strpos( $url, '?' ) !== false ) {

            $url = substr( $url, 0, strpos( $url, '?' ) );

        };

        $slugs = ( startsWith( $url, '/' ) ? explode( '/', substr( $url, 1, -1 ) ) : explode( '/', substr( $url, 1 ) ) );

        return end( $slugs );

    };

};
```

On the front end:

```
<?php

echo get_the_current_slug();
```

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to only get the current page slug, for example in the page `mywebsite.com/hoodies` I only want to get the `hoodies` part. 
I tried your snippet and I can successfully get the `hoodies` part but it's also logging other values like `wp-cron.php`, `favicon.ico`, `wp-admin`. I used polyfill for `str_contains` and `str_end_with` since I'm using PHP 7.4.20.

Comment: `end( $slugs )` should only give you the last slug from the url. The other stuff you're getting are not from my snippet.

Comment: I've edited the answer, made it `PHP < 8.0.0` compatible. Both are working on my end to successfully retrieve the current slug.

Comment: You are right, I'm new to PHP and thought it was not possible to `echo` from a plugin. I was logging the `$slugs` from your code with the `_error_log` in my original post. With your `echo end ( $slugs )` there is only the slug that shows on the page, so that's the desired behaviour and it works. However, it's weird because the shop items are correctly filtered but the filter is not ticked and the query is not showing (the URL should be like `website.com/hoodies/?_categories=hoodies` but it's like `website.com/hoodies` instead).
At this point I think I'll have to check with the plugin support.

Comment: I tried your new snippet. Your snippet is perfectly correct and the correct value is showed. I'll try to reproduce my issue on a fresh Wordpress install and if I still get the issue I'll contact the plugin's author, because if I use the `_error_log` function from my original post, multiple values are still logged (with your last snippet : `hoodies` and `favicon.ic` )

Comment: Yeah, I cannot speak about the plugin behavior. I'm guessing you're trying to implement a no refresh filtering. As this is plugin related you should refer to them.